# ForceDarkHelper в MIUI 12

Tags: android, logcat, xiaomi

MIUI обновился до 12 версии. И теперь Logcat при работе с UI засыпает бесполезными сообщениями вида:

`D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: org.myapp activity: org.myapp.activities.MyActivity@123d57c`

Меняется только название Activity.

Есть информация, что это за `ForceDarkHelper`?

Comment: Не узнал что это?

Answer (score 2):

В MIUI 12 сделали интелектуальную темную тему. Система сама перекрашивает приложения если они не поддерживают темную тему. Судя по всему этот сервис и есть ForceDarkHelper. А ExcludeList это в настройках задаваемый список приложений, которые нельзя перекрашивать